# Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap' not found

Tags: magento2

The website was working fine without any issue, but now i am getting the following error "Fatal error: Class `'Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap'` not found in **`/public_html/app/autoload.php`** on line 40".

Please suggest what to do.
Thanks